# Should loft insulation cover wall cavities?

Tags: insulation, attic

When insulating a loft at ceiling level with mineral wool type material, should the insulation cover the exposed [wall cavities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavity_wall) for external walls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insulation should cover the top plate of the wall.  This gives you a complete thermal envelope.  Covering the wall cavities will help keep cold air from coming up to the upper areas.

Comment: I agree, but insulation isn't intended to block airflow. (You probably meant heat transfer via conduction.)